# package autonum needs the obsolete etex package

Tags: e-tex, autonum

With an up to date TL 2015, the following minimal example:

```
% \RequirePackage{etex}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{l3keys2e}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{autonum}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

is non working:

```
Package etex Warning: Extended allocation already in use.
(etex)                etex.sty code will not be used.
(etex)                To force etex package to load, add
(etex)                \RequirePackage{etex}
(etex)                at the start of the document.

)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.905 \globcount
                \ettl@for@nested
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.905 \globcount\ettl@for@nested

?
```

because of the `autonum` package. But, it becomes working as soon as:

- either one of the packages before `autonum` is removed (not relevant in my case: I need these packages),
- or `autonum` is loaded before the other packages (not relevant in my case: I also need the `cleveref` package which is required to be loaded as the last one, with two exceptions: `hypdvips` and... `autonum`),
- or the `etex` package is loaded, as suggested in the above warning (but this package is nowadays considered as [obsolete](http://ctan.org/pkg/etex)).

Do you understand what's going on? Is it safe to use `etex` though it is obsolete?

Comment: It should be safe; please tell the author to update the package.

Comment: @egreg What kind of update the author should perform?

Comment: Not calling etex, for instance. Which means not using `etextools`, which is buggy and not recommended.

Comment: Since this is a package bug, i suggest closing this question.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Okay, I close it.

Comment: @Johannes_B Well, in order to close a question, one has to select a reason in a list of imposed ones and none is related to "package bug".

Comment: Bugs are considered as off-topic. But since you have an answer with 8 upvotes, just leave it :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `autonum` package loads `etextools`, a package I don't recommend using and that has been declared “dead” by its author, as far as I remember.

For strange reasons, after loading `etex`, the package has a declaration `\globcount\ettl@for@nested` which could have been `\newcount` from the beginning.

Workaround: define `\globcount` to be `\newcount` before loading `autonum`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{l3keys2e}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{glossaries}

%\expandafter\def\csname ver@etex.sty\endcsname{3000/12/31}
\let\globcount\newcount
\usepackage{autonum}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Uncomment the line starting with `%` if you also want to get rid of the warning about `etex`.

Comment: Your solution does not scale well.  The code will break on January 1st, 3001.  In other words, have my upvote ;)

Comment: @HenriMenke I did it with the secret hope that by 3001-01-01 these issues will have been straightened up: LaTeX3 will have been released. Perhaps.

Comment: It's not even the year 3001 yet and an update to etex.sty (version 2.5) has been submitted to ctan to address this issue.

Comment: I had a similar problem when `autonum` complained about `\ifempty` already being defined. In my case, `\undef\ifempty` before loading `autonum` was sufficient (I believe `\undef` comes from the `etoolbox` package).