# Package linegoal: Undefined control sequence. [\globcount]

Tags: linegoal

I tried to compile some projects which were fine in the past but now give some errors. Sublime Text 3 console says:

```
Errors:

E:\Programme\MiKTeX_2_9\tex\latex\linegoal\linegoal.sty:51: Undefined control sequence. [\globcount]
E:\Programme\MiKTeX_2_9\tex\latex\linegoal\linegoal.sty:51: Undefined control sequence. [\globcount \LNGL@unique]
E:\Programme\MiKTeX_2_9\tex\latex\linegoal\linegoal.sty:52: Undefined control sequence. [\globdimen]
E:\Programme\MiKTeX_2_9\tex\latex\linegoal\linegoal.sty:52: Undefined control sequence. [\globdimen \LNGL@tempdim]
```

And TeXWorks console says:

```
))) (E:\Programme\MiKTeX_2_9\tex\latex\oberdiek\zref-savepos.sty)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.51 \globcount
                \LNGL@unique
?
```

I made several updates to my packages (with MikTeX) over the last weeks.

Would be nice if someone has a clue, why after the updates these errors appear.

---

EDIT: The following warning appears in the log earlier:

```
Package etex Warning: Extended allocation already in use.
(etex)                etex.sty code will not be used.
(etex)                To force etex package to load, add
(etex)                \RequirePackage{etex}
(etex)                at the start of the document.
```

The File list (`\listfiles`):

```
 *File List*
subfiles.cls    2012/05/23 Federico Garcia
verbatim.sty    2014/10/28 v1.5q LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
../Root/Root.tex
scrartcl.cls    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script document class (article)
scrkbase.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent ba
sics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize12pt.clo    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script font size class option (12pt)
typearea.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (type area)
subfiles.sty    2012/05/23 Federico Garcia
   babel.sty    2015/08/03 3.9m The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
 ngerman.ldf    2013/12/13 v2.7 German support for babel (new orthography)
 lmodern.sty    2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2015/09/07 v1.1p UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2015/09/07 v1.1p UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2015/09/07 v1.1p UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2015/09/07 v1.1p UTF-8 support for inputenc
../../../../../corporate_layout.tex
everypage.sty    2007/06/20 1.1 Hooks to run on every page
scrpage2.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (page head and foot)
../../../FOS_AP_12_MT.tex
    ulem.sty    2012/05/18
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
mathtools.sty    2015/11/12 v1.18 mathematical typesetting tools
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 mhsetup.sty    2010/01/21 v1.2a programming setup (MH)
  cancel.sty    2013/04/12 v2.2 Cancel math terms
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  bclogo.sty    2011/07/06 v2.26
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
enumitem.sty    2011/09/28 v3.5.2 Customized lists
multicol.sty    2015/08/19 v1.8n multicolumn formatting (FMi)
tabularx.sty    2014/10/28 v2.10 `tabularx' package (DPC)
   array.sty    2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
    tabu.sty    2011/02/26 v2.8 - flexible LaTeX tabulars (FC)
varwidth.sty    2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
longtable.sty    2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
colortbl.sty    2012/02/13 v1.0a Color table columns (DPC)
 makeidx.sty    2014/09/29 v1.0m Standard LaTeX package
 eurosym.sty    1998/08/06 v1.1 European currency symbol ``Euro''
 textpos.sty    2014/01/03 v1.7j
linegoal.sty    2011/02/25 v2.9 - Measuring the remaining width of the line
    etex.sty    2015/09/02 v2.4 eTeX basic definition package (PEB,DPC)
    zref.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 A new reference scheme for LaTeX (HO)
zref-base.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module base for zref (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
zref-savepos.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module savepos for zref (HO)
  icomma.sty    2002/03/10 v2.0 (WaS)
pgfplots.sty    2015/05/02 v1.12.1 Data Visualization (1.12.1)
circuitikz.sty    2015/05/15 The CircuiTikz circuit drawing package version 0.4

 wasysym.sty    2003/10/30 v2.0 Wasy-2 symbol support package
   xfrac.sty    2015/12/20 v6326 L3 Experimental split-level fractions
   expl3.sty    2015/12/20 v6326 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2015/12/20 v6326 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2015/11/11 v6250 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
l3keys2e.sty    2015/12/20 v6326 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
textcomp.sty    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
  ts1enc.dfu    2015/09/07 v1.1p UTF-8 support for inputenc
  xparse.sty    2015/12/20 v6326 L3 Experimental document command parser
xtemplate.sty    2015/12/20 v6326 L3 Experimental prototype document functions
 xifthen.sty    2015/11/05 v1.4.0 Extended ifthen features
 ifmtarg.sty    2009/09/02 v1.2a check for an empty argument
  framed.sty    2011/10/22 v 0.96: framed or shaded text with page breaks
 paracol.sty    2015/10/10 v1.32 
titlesec.sty    2011/12/15 v2.10.0 Sectioning titles
booktabs.sty    2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
 polynom.sty    2006/04/20 0.17 (CH,HA)
mathastext.sty    2015/10/31 v1.3h Use the text font in math mode (jfB)
../../../../../own_math_ops_and_commands.tex
../../../../../own_tikz_sets_and_commands.tex
  ts1cmr.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
  t1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
supp-pdf.mkii
../Deckblatt.tex
  ot1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  omllmm.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omslmsy.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omxlmex.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
   uwasy.fd    2003/10/30 v2.0 Wasy-2 symbol font definitions
 ***********
```

Comment: the package could be updated not to use that (`\globcount` comes from the more or less obsolete etex package) but you can add `\let\globcount\newcount` and it should work.

Comment: This came up yesterday so must be a dup, I'll find it....

Comment: different package but essentially this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285950/package-autonum-needs-the-obsolete-etex-package/285953#285953

Comment: You presumably had a warning from the etex package _before_ this error.

Comment: With an up-to-date TeX Live I have no issue here: can you ad `\listfiles` to your input and edit the `File list` from the `.log` into the question?

Comment: @JosephWright OP doesn't say but it occurs if etex is loaded late (when the extended range is already in use) the package does give a warning in that case that it is quitting.

Comment: Actually I didn't load the etex package anyway. But inserting it at the beginning works fine, thx.

Comment: The point is that _linegoal_ loads etex and with your preamble in the order it is that means etex gets loaded too late to be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example is

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\x{\newcount\zz\newcount\zz\newcount\zz\newcount\zz\newcount\zz\newcount\zz}
\def\xx{\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x}
\xx\xx
\usepackage{linegoal}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Note that you get a very explicit message from etex before the error

```
Package etex Warning: Extended allocation already in use.
(etex)                etex.sty code will not be used.
(etex)                To force etex package to load, add
(etex)                \RequirePackage{etex}
(etex)                at the start of the document.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(./ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-savepos.sty)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.51 \globcount
                \LNGL@unique
```

So if you loaded the etex package earlier as the warning suggests then the error would not occur.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etex}
\def\x{\newcount\zz\newcount\zz\newcount\zz\newcount\zz\newcount\zz\newcount\zz}
\def\xx{\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x}
\xx\xx
\usepackage{linegoal}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

However I may update etex.sty to define `\globcount` when making that warning so that this particular error does not occur, I'll update ctan if tests prove OK.

Note that this document produces no error if you use version 2.5 of etex.sty submitted to CTAN a few seconds ago.

Comment: Thanks. You mentioned that etex is more or less obsolete. Is there something not obsolte-based way to obtain the functionality of the linegoal package?

Comment: @RafaelWörner as far as I know there's nothing particularly wrong with linegoal (although I don't know the package that well) it just needs updating not to load etex.sty (and will need updating in texlive 2016 for some changes coming up in luatex) but for the problem here just not using etex.sty would be enough. I just checked and I mailed the author of linegoal (I mailed all authors of all packages using etex.sty) on 07/07/2015 after the 2015 latex release had made etex.sty obsolete (as it now uses extended allocation by default)