# Warning: Extended allocation already in use. etex.sty code will not be used

Tags: warnings

These are the imports for my latex project. I am wondering how to fix the compile time following the warning, I don't know which package is causing it. Apparently, [this question has been asked before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285950/package-autonum-needs-the-obsolete-etex-package) but I am not using `autonum` package so I am not sure.

```
Package etex Warning: Extended allocation already in use.
etex.sty code will not be used.
To force etex package to load, add \RequirePackage{etex}
at the start of the document.
```

Latex:

```
   \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usepackage{soul}
    \usepackage{spverbatim}
    \usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{bookmark}% faster updated bookmarks
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage{algorithm}
    \usepackage{algpseudocode}
    \usepackage{enumerate}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{fancyvrb}
    \usepackage[super]{nth}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{linegoal}
    \usepackage{calc}
    \usepackage{tocloft}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{tikz-qtree}
    \usepackage{forest}
    \usepackage{titling}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{abstract}
    \usepackage{booktabs} % for the second rendering
    \usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % load this package *last*
    \title{Warning issue}
    
    \lstset{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    columns=flexible,
    breaklines=true
    }
    \date{February 2023}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    \begin{lstlisting}
    Package etex Warning: Extended allocation already in use. etex.sty code will not be used. To force etex package to load, add \RequirePackage{etex} at the start of the document.
    \end{lstlisting}
    
    \end{document}
```

[Overleaf project](https://www.overleaf.com/read/yrsdsdwmcbqw)

Comment: FYI you should load `hyperref` after `booktabs` and before `cleveref` too, you have correctly identified that `cleveref` should be loaded last (`% load this package *last*`), `hyperref` is the same except for `glossaries`, `cleveref` etc it is described in the [`hyperref` documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) (section 3 and 11)

Answer (score 6):

Do you *really* use all those packages? It is bad practice to load packages you do not use.

The problem here is `linegoal` which is unmaintained and has not been updated since 2010. It includes the obsolete `etex` package which does nothing other than warn it should not be used.

If you really need `linegoal` just ignore the warning. A fix would be to change `linegoal` not to load `etex` but loading it with a warning that it does nothing is more or less the same thing.

Do not avoid the warning by forcing `etex` to be loaded earlier, that might be needed for some specific legacy documents but it will break a lot of current code.